# Javascript - I want to use WebRTC to record multiple tabs

Tags: javascript, webrtc, mediarecorder

I am able to record a single tab at the moment, and then create a media recorder from its stream. I want to be able to switch to another tab and continue this same recording on another tab and then provide a final concatenated video in the end. How can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use this as an example for what you want to do:

```
let currentStream = null;
let mediaRecorder = null;
let recordedChunks = [];

// Start recording for a new tab
function startRecording(stream) {
currentStream = stream;
mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(stream);

mediaRecorder.ondataavailable = (event) => {
    if (event.data.size > 0) {
    recordedChunks.push(event.data);
    }
};

mediaRecorder.start();
}

// Stop recording for the current tab
function stopRecording() {
if (mediaRecorder) {
    mediaRecorder.stop();
    currentStream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    currentStream = null;
    mediaRecorder = null;
}
}

// Concatenate recorded videos
function concatenateVideos() {
const finalBlob = new Blob(recordedChunks, { type: 'video/webm' });
// You can now use the finalBlob as the concatenated video
}

// Example usage
startRecording(firstTabStream);
// Switch to another tab and call startRecording with the new tab's stream
stopRecording(); // When switching tabs or ending recording
concatenateVideos(); // To get the final concatenated video
```

Comment: This does not concatenate the second video sequentially. For example, if my first recording is 3 seconds long, and second one is 8 seconds long, as a result, i get an 8 seconds long recording which has first 3 seconds from first one and last 5 seconds from second one.
What i want is a concatenated 11 seconds long recording as a result.